# Angular setup test weird output

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I created a new angular project, i wanted to setup the tests based on the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing).

So i ran:

```sh
ng test
```

But the output is not what i expected:

```
t̸̡̙̪͙͎̼̬̮̣̜̜̤͉̬͚̰͚̙͉̮̥̜̞͕̬̝̻͕̬̭͍̦̫̳͈̯̰̳̹̭̦͈̦͔̲̱̒͗̄͊ͥ̈̏́ͧ̊̔̿̚͟͡͝ͅͅé̴̝͍͉̣̹̯̖̯͓̘̠͇͍͙̭̙̻̬͖̫̯̘̟͎̤̯ͭ͐ͥ̒ͦ͒̓̀̐̋ͤ͟ș̷̴͔͈͎͖̙̞̹̍̓ͬ̓ͬ̈̓̃ͦ̌̔͒̊ͧ̓̂ͦ͝͞ț̨̧͍̩̬̟̺̦͇̜̜̣̳͇͓͂̓̊̂ͭ̏̏ͩ͌̎̿̈͗ͧ̓́̒̿͘͟į̰̲̤̖̲͇̲̣̻̘̗̤͍̖͖̠̖̟͔̞͎͚͎͉̫͇͍̻͙͚͈̥͎̼̻̝̜͍̭̗̩̳̖͙̫͈͕̩̱̹̮̹̯̪͚̺͔͙̜͉̣͚ͤ͑̓̅̈͆̀̃ͮ̋ͤͧ́̕ͅͅͅͅn̶̵̰̜̲̗͎̯͈̰̰̼̯̦̞̫̞̠̥͈̖̬̼̖̻̹̤͎̥̳̠̟̺̮̯̭̟̮̻̫̗͈͖͖͍͔̤̉́̈͆̅ͣ̀̈̃̈̅̓ͤ̀̏̾ͣ̅́ͅͅͅgͦ͐̏ͧ̌̍ ҉̷̨̣̰͈̪̭͔̼͈͕͇̼͚͖͎̞͍̮̬̣̩͍̼͈̟̖̜͎͉̳̱͇̱̤̦̤̩̞̮̳͜͡ͅ ̈̌̇ͥͬ͐̌ͣ̒͋͗́͛ͩ̓̈̃̚͟ ҉̵̬͕̦̤̰͚̬͎̗̰͈̳̱͇̯̟̼̜̜̰͖ṱ̶̨̢̛̩̫̮̺̣̯̬̣͎̠̟̤͎̞͕̦̠̰̫̱̖̱̪͙͙̫̞͔͙̜͓͔͙͉̗͙̞̳̜̰͕͇͚͓̞̭̲̰͙̲̲̤͇̘̥̲̉ͬͪ̇͡ͅͅͅͅè̴̸̛̪͓͚̘̞̙͈̫̦͓̰͚̼͇̦̤͔͈̫͍̪̠͍̬̥̭̙̠̥̗̺͇͙̣̲͈̞̲͍̻͓̖͙͙ͨ̏̀͆ͤͮ̋̾̋͘s̵̞̞͈̮̫̭͔̬̹̻͍̳͕͎̭͎̗̗͚͔̖̰̭̣̙̪̱͓̥̺̣̠̗̝͔̞̱̩̥̲̰̠͎̱͓̻̼͓̪̩̼̤̍̍̈̑ͤ̓̓̉̓̇ͨͮ̋̋̀͋̕͜t̜̰̮͉̲̺̣ͧ̅͋ͥ͊ͤͭͪ͑ͪ͐̍̑ͬ̄͐̌́̚͡i̴̪̹̲̲͚͈̝̼͙̊͂ͪͨ̌ͨ̊̏͆ͧ̉̅́̀̀̋͂ͦ͟͢͞n̴̡̖̖̬̪̲̰̪̝͓͖̺̯̯̬͖͚͚̼͖͖̠̝̙͈̥̩̤̮̲̭̝̯͎͚͎̳̤͚͈͓̟͓̟͓̪͎̮̥̩̯͙̞͔̻̹̖͚ͣͤ̃͒̈̑ͩͩͩ͢͡ͅģ̶̠̗͔̖͉̲̝͉̻̟̮̤̖͈̯͎̮̰͈͙͔̽̑ͦ̇͑̆́͐͐̅̇̓ͭ͑̅́ ̧̢̙̱͓͈̯̮̤̬͍̪̬̲̠̖͎̙̠̖̘ͬ̇͛̏̆̎̀͘͡ͅt̴̸̢̝̯̮̣͖̝̫̞͍̹̯̱̣̦͙̲͇̙͈̗̭͉̪͕̬͚̺̝͍̼̹̼͉̯ͫ̌̅̓̽̒͆͌̇́̊͟ͅͅe̟̲̥̰̤͍̭͙̦̙̤̬̳͍̰͙͕̞̜̺̰̻͇̞̱̗̤̤͔̲̠̯͕̳ͯ̄̂ͥ̊́͘͘͘ṣ̸̴̢̯̯͉͎̥̤͔̫̭̝̩̥̟̓͊ͮ̃ͭ̽ͯ̈̏̆̇̏̈̏ͫ͘͢ͅt̑̅͒ͨͩ̐̈ͤ̀ ҉̴̻̲̥͔̼̖̥͕͔̥͔̭͖̼̹̹͎͓͇̬̼̲͎̦͕͇͕̫̮̠̫̻͎̮̻̗̗͓
```

I tried to update `ng` and create a new project and change nothing. Then i ran again

```sh
ng test
```

But i still have the same result, how would you fix that ?

Comment: Hello. This is probably OS IDE/termninal specific. Does every ng cli command look weird or  just ng test/

Comment: prolly https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/dev-corrupts-npm-libs-colors-and-faker-breaking-thousands-of-apps/

Comment: @danvid No it's only for `ng test`, other command on ng cli works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is more details about the fix. It is indeed the problem that @Vikas mentioned.

To put the problem in evidence :

- launch `ng test >> "res.txt"`
- When the file `res.txt` grows stop the command with CTRL+C and open it with Notepadd++
- You can see code like that "!             H|H|H|H|H           H__________________________________             H|┬º|┬º|┬º|H           H|* * * * *"  and it ends with the name of Carl Pilcher

If you search for "Pilcher" in `node_modules`, you will find his name in `node_modules\colors\lib\custom\american.js`

To solve the problem, as mentioned :

- launch `npm install` if package-lock.json has been deleted so that it is created again
- Change the version of colors :
  before :

```json
"colors": {
  "version": "1.4.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.4.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-5QhJWPFZqkKIieXJPpCprdOytvH7v0AGWpu9K2jZ4LWkGg3dVBNoYPgGGRpEsc0jb8Boy0ElYrdjH9uXfhRSqw==",
  "dev": true
},
```

after :

```json
"colors": {
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.4.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-a+UqTh4kgZg/SlGvfbzDHpgRu7AAQOmmqRHJnxhRZICKFUT91brVhNNt58CMWU9PsBbv3PDCZUHbVxuDiH2mtA==",
  "dev": true
},
```

- launch a `npm install` to downgrade the color package


  The best way would be to ask the editor to upgrade without the `node_modules\colors\lib\custom\american.js`

Comment: Instead of manipulating the file `package-lock.json`, you can also enter the following command: `npm install colors@1.4.0`

In the meantime, NPM has also removed the defective version.

Answer (score 4):

As @Vikas mentioned it was linked to that news: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/dev-corrupts-npm-libs-colors-and-faker-breaking-thousands-of-apps/

To fix it I searched for `/colors` inside my `package-lock.json`. I found two occurrences:

I changed the version from `1.4.2` to `1.4.0`, the lines look like that:

```json
    "node_modules/colors": {
      "version": "1.4.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.4.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-a+UqTh4kgZg/SlGvfbzDHpgRu7AAQOmmqRHJnxhRZICKFUT91brVhNNt58CMWU9PsBbv3PDCZUHbVxuDiH2mtA==",
      "dev": true,
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.1.90"
      }
    },
```

```json
    "colors": {
      "version": "1.4.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.4.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-a+UqTh4kgZg/SlGvfbzDHpgRu7AAQOmmqRHJnxhRZICKFUT91brVhNNt58CMWU9PsBbv3PDCZUHbVxuDiH2mtA==",
      "dev": true
    },
```

Comment: Instead of manipulating the file `package-lock.json`, you can also enter the following command: `npm install colors@1.4.0`

In the meantime, NPM has also removed the defective version.

Comment: I already have colors 1.4.0. but i still get that